# Remove row in dx-pivot-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am creating a project using Angular with Typescript and for the library I use DevExtreme.

Is there any option to remove some row in DevExtreme PivotGrid? Regarding their documentation and their forum, proper way to do this is to set `hideEmptySummaryCells` property to true on the grid and also change `calculateSummaryValue` on the field in that manner to return null value if we want to remove some row, but the problem is that `calculateSummaryValue` have signature `calculateSummaryValue?: ((e: dxPivotGridSummaryCell) => number);` and of course we cannot return null. Please look at the following sample:

```
var entity: Field = {
                    area: "data",
                    dataField: "countOfItems",
                    caption: 'Count of Items',
                    isMeasure: false,
                    expanded: false,
                    filterType: 'include',
                    filterValues: [], 
                    visible: true,
                    calculateSummaryValue: function(e: dxPivotGridSummaryCell) {
                      //Cannot return null
                      return 0;
                    }
                 };
```

Thank you for the answer, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I find out a workaround, it is not completely in manner of typescript and angular, because it avoids type checking, I add `//@ts-ignore` above `calculateSummaryValue` and that avoid type checking for the line below

```
var entity: Field = {
                area: "data",
                dataField: "countOfItems",
                caption: 'Count of Items',
                isMeasure: false,
                expanded: false,
                filterType: 'include',
                filterValues: [], 
                visible: true,
                // @ts-ignore
                calculateSummaryValue: function(e: dxPivotGridSummaryCell) {
                  //Cannot return null
                  return 0;
                }
             };
```